# why there is no option in the reference and resource row when i add language in localizations on xcode

Tags: xcode, localization

1.has selected project.
2.It does not exist any storyboard or xib file include launchScreen file.
3.The project has proceed for a long time.
how can i implement multiple language.

screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Documentation screenshot:

[image]

I read the official document about that and i found this.